# Find all connected nodes in adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an adjacency list for a DAG, and I need to find all connected nodes from all nodes, for example : for a DAG below

```
1 -> 3 -> 4  
2 -> 4  
3 -> 2    
4 -> 5  
5 -> NULL
```

I need this :

```
1 -> {2, 3, 4, 5}
2 -> {4, 5}
3 -> {2, 4, 5}
4 -> {5}
5 -> NULL
```

Is there any efficient algorithm for this ?

Comment: Shouldn't 2 be in the connected node set of 3?

Comment: So what you want is the adjacency lists of the transitive closure of the dag? Shouldn't be too hard to find that, a straightforward implementation (topologically sort, add transitivity edges in reverse topological order) takes Theta(n^3). An asymptotically more efficient way would be to build the adjacency matrix and use fast matrix multiplication to get that and extract the adjacency lists from that. Beyond that, google is your friend ("fast algorithm transitive closure").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned a DAG you can use following algorithm to get all connected components to given vertex :-

> 1. Do a Topological Sort of the all nodes in graph
> 2. Start in decreasing order of the sorted nodes.
> 3. Maintain a Set of all connected nodes for each node.
> 4. Sort adjacency list of vertex u in toposort order
> 5. For vertex u and each edge(u,v) and !Set(u).contains(v) do Set(u) = Set(u) union Set(v) union v
> 6. Do this for all node in decreasing order of toposort.

**Time Complexity :-**

**Toposort :** `O(E)`

**Caculating Set :** `O(V^2*logV)`

**Total:** `O(V^2*logV)`

**Example:-**

```
1 -> 3 -> 4  
2 -> 4  
3 -> 2    
4 -> 5  
5 -> NULL  

TopoSort: 1,3,2,4,5

Visiting in descending order :-
1. Set(5) = {null}
2. Set(4) = Set(5) + 5 = {5}
3. Set(2) = Set(4) + 4 = {4,5}
4. Set(3) = Set(2) + 2 = {2,4,5}
5. Set(1) = Set(3) + 1 = {1,2,4,5}
```

Comment: I don't think your analysis for 5 is correct. You could have Omega(n) edges (u,v) where !Set(u).contains(v) but Set(v) = Set(u) \ v or at least something with overlap Omega(n) with Set(u), which means you could be taking the union of Omega(n^2) elements, costing you Omega(V^2 log V) for every node, giving a total of Omega(V^3 log V). Vikesh did basically the same without the (asymptotically not helpful) !Set(u).contains(v) check.

Comment: @G.Bach I do think that there will be cases where there is overlap like you say but if there is higher out degree for a node in graph then that in general reduces the depth of the DAG hence in that case the sizes of SET(v)'s will be small because there are no cycles in graph. So i think its safe to say its O(V^2*logV) in average

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do it is by recursively descending through the graph. Pseudocode:

```
function get_connected_nodes(node){
    nodes = set();
    foreach(child in node.children){
        nodes.add(child);
        nodes = nodes.union(get_connected_nodes(child));
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Sample Python implementation:

```
adjacencies = {
    1: [3],
    2: [4],
    3: [2, 4],
    4: [5],
    5: []
}

def get_connected_nodes(node):
    nodes = set()
    for child in adjacencies[node]:
        nodes.add(child)
        nodes = nodes | get_connected_nodes(child)
    return nodes

for i in range(1, 6):
    print i, ":", get_connected_nodes(i)

#output:
#1 : set([2, 3, 4, 5])
#2 : set([4, 5])
#3 : set([2, 4, 5])
#4 : set([5])
#5 : set([])
```

---

Edit: For improved performance, storing previously computed results can save you from traversing a node more than once. Pseudocode:

```
connected_results = dict();
function get_connected_nodes(node){
    if(!connected_results.has_key(node)){
        nodes = set();
        foreach(child in node.children){
            nodes.add(child);
            nodes = nodes.union(get_connected_nodes(child));
        }
        connected_results[node] = nodes;
    }
    return connected_results[node];
}
```

Sample Python implementation:

```
def memoize(fn):
    answers = {}
    def memoized_fn(*args):
        if args not in answers:
            answers[args] = fn(*args)
        return answers[args]
    return memoized_fn

adjacencies = {
    1: [3],
    2: [4],
    3: [2, 4],
    4: [5],
    5: []
}

@memoize
def get_connected_nodes(node):
    nodes = set()
    for child in adjacencies[node]:
        nodes.add(child)
        nodes = nodes | get_connected_nodes(child)
    return nodes

for i in range(1, 6):
    print i, ":", get_connected_nodes(i)
```

Comment: This looks like it could take Theta(n^4) for dense DAGs, since you always recompute get_connected_nodes(v) for every incoming edge to v. Maybe it'd be better to store fully computed "outgoing closures" for single vertices once they've been calculated.

Comment: Yes, it's not very efficient as-is. Storing already-computed results would give a fair performance boost for dense graphs.

Comment: Just figured out another problem with this is that simple concatenation of reachability lists will give us many duplicates and possibly reachability lists with Theta(n^2) length. Eliminating those would cost another Theta(n^3).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by duplicates. By definition, a set can only contain unique values.

Comment: I misread your code, I thought you were using lists instead of sets. Still, The way it is, taking the union of Theta(n) sets with Theta(n) elements each should still require Omega(n^2) time, no? Doing that a total of Omega(n) times will give us Omega(n^3) time required.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for seems to be the adjacency lists of the transitive closure of your DAG.

Since you're going for efficiency: you've got a DAG, so it doesn't have cycles, which means you can decide reachability for all vertices from a given start vertex s in O(m+n) via DFS/BFS. Do this once for each of the n vertices, and you end up with O(n*(m+n)) which is O(n*m) for graphs where you have Omega(n) edges.

If you've got gigantic dense DAGs, the matrix multiplication approach (take the adjacency matrix, square it, you've got an edge (i,j) whenever adjacencyMatrix[i][j] > 0) with a fast matrix muliplication may be faster; make sure to benchmark if relevant, since despite the asymptotic superiority of the matrix multiplication approach, it does tend to not outperform the above approach in practice for most applications, apparently.

And if you're really dealing with dense graphs (i.e. Omega(n^2) edges) you may want to consider using Ford-Warshall as well, even thought it won't outperform the BFS approach, purely because you'll probably find an implementation of it lying around somewhere (if not, google helps).

Answer (score 0):

You are given a directed acyclic graph (DAG) and you intend to find all the nodes reachable from a given node. Consider the following recurrence solution, where `f(u)` denotes the set of nodes reachable from u.

[image]

This simply means that the nodes you can reach from `u` is the union of the nodes you can reach from all its out-neighbors (adjacent nodes). This can easily be achieved with DFS (depth-first search) along with memoization of previously computed `f(u)` sets. This approach has a time-complexity of `O(|E| + |V| + |E||V|log(|V|))` and an additional space-complexity of `O(|V|^2)`. Note that this algorithm doesn't scale well to very large graphs due to the `|V|^2` memory requirement.

The following C++ code demonstrates this approach :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<set>

using namespace std;

#define FOR(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
#define FORS(i,s,n) for(int i=s;i<n;++i)
#define MAX 1000000

#define WHITE 0
#define GRAY 1
#define BLACK 2

void dfs_visit(vector<int> adj[], int u, int color[], set<int> cache[])
{
 color[u]=GRAY;
 int len = adj[u].size();

 FOR(i,len)
 {
  int v = adj[u][i];
  if(color[v]==WHITE)
  {
   dfs_visit(adj,v,color,cache);
  }          
 }  

 // Before coloring a node black, set its f(u) to be the union of the f(v) of its neighbours for all v
 FOR(i,len)
 {
    int v = adj[u][i];
    cache[u].insert(v);
    // This will take time logarithmic in the size of f(u) since each insertion requires comparison for uniqueness
    for(set<int>::iterator it = cache[v].begin(); it!=cache[v].end(); ++it)
    {
        cache[u].insert(*it);
    }
 }

    color[u]=BLACK;   
}

void dfs(vector<int> adj[], set<int> cache[], int n)
{
 int color[n];
 memset(color, WHITE, sizeof(color));

 FOR(i,n)
 {
    if(color[i]==WHITE)
    {
     dfs_visit(adj, i, color, cache);
    }                      
 }      
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);

    // To handle 0-based index, initialize as n+1
    set<int> cache[n+1];
    vector<int> adj[n+1];

    FOR(i,m)
    {
        int u,v;
        scanf("%d%d", &u, &v);
        adj[u].push_back(v);
    }

    dfs(adj, cache, n);

    FORS(i,1,n)
    {
        set<int> fu = cache[i];
        printf("%d->{", i); 

        for(set<int>::iterator it=fu.begin(); it!=fu.end(); ++it)
        {
            printf("%d,", *it);     
        }

        printf("}\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input (N=Number of nodes, M=Number of edges, M lines follow with edge list):

```
5 6
1 3
2 4
3 4 
3 2
4 5
```

Output:

```
1->{2,3,4,5,}
2->{4,5,}
3->{2,4,5,}
4->{5,}
```

Comment: Where does the V log V come in, and how do you eliminate duplicates in the outneighbour sets in less than (worst case) V^2 time?

Comment: @G.Bach It does not take V^2 time to eliminate duplicates in an optimized data structure like the `set`. The set `insert` method checks if an element already exists before inserting, which is logarithmic in the size of the set, which, in the worst case, would be |V|.

Comment: @G.Bach: However, I did miss out the `|E|` component in the `|V|log|V|` part. `|V|log|V|` for the union of two sets is repeated |E| times.

Comment: Now it's wrong again though, since you're at most trying to add V elements for each of the at most V outneighbours, so using a balanced search tree based elimination of duplicates is in V^2 log V. Using hashing, you can eliminate the log V (at least if you're happy with V^2 expected time). Doing the whole thing will then cost you V*(E + V + V^2) expected time, giving us V^3 expected time.